# Laravel error after changing php version

Tags: php, version, laravel-5.6, php-parse-error

I just setup php 7.0.27 in both webserver and cli. My laravel project was working just fine before in php 7.2. When I try run command `php artisan serve` it shows an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable 
(T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/pmanager/pmanager/vendor/symfony/console
/Output/Output.php on line 40
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16674) github discussion which says that the solution is installing same versions in cli and webserver, which, in my case is fine. I have **7.0.27** in both.

Another thing they are pointing it out is laravel shows this **error with php 7.0**. **I cannot change my php version to 7.1 or 7.2 because I must stick with it so as to run magento 2.1 projects.**

Any help without changing php version would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you removed the vendor dir and re installed dependencies? The latest symfony console requires PHP >= 7.1.3 so dependencies might not be compatible anymore

Comment: @JimL I did nothing to my laravel project.

Comment: That might be the problem, you have installed the dependencies on PHP 7.2 so you are probably using dependencies that are not compatible with PHP < 7.2

Comment: Is there any way I could fix this without starting again with empty project?

Comment: Yes, delete the vendor dir and reinstall the dependencies.

Comment: How to reinstall dependencies, I'm quite new to composer. I tried `composer install` but it shows error that the current setup requires php7.1 or more.

Comment: Then your laravel app requires PHP > 7.1. There are ways to configure your server to run multiple php versions, you may also run it on a different (virtual?) server, in a docker container or similar

Comment: Okay thank you for that suggestion I'll try that one.

Answer (score 1):

you can downgrade your laravel 5.6 project to 5.5!!

> - Changing the value of the Laravel version inside the `composer.json` file to the laravel 5.5.
> - Delete `/vendor` folder and run `composer install`